# Parse Git Branch Stopped Working (OSX)

Tags: git, zsh, osx-mavericks

I use a method called `parse_git_branch` which is called by my PROMPT. I'm using zshell, but I don't understand why this would stop working.

Here's the function:

```
parse_git_branch() {
    git_status="$(git status 2> /dev/null)"
pattern="^# On branch ([^[:space:]]*)"
    if [[ ! ${git_status} =~ "working directory clean" ]]; then
        state="*"
    fi
    if [[ ${git_status} =~ ${pattern} ]]; then
      branch=${match[1]}
      echo "(${branch}${state})"
    fi
}
```

and here's the output of a `git status`:

```
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
```

but yet calling `parse_git_branch` echoes nothing to the screen.

**What could've changed?** I did just install the latest version of Xcode.

Git version: `git version 1.8.5.2 (Apple Git-48)` (which doesn't look familiar)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line

`pattern="^# On branch ([^[:space:]]*)`

to

`pattern="On branch ([^[:space:]]*)"`

Not sure how those worked with the older git, but anyway...

---

New version to work with newer Git (uses tree instead of directory)

```
parse_git_branch() {
    git_status="$(git status 2> /dev/null)"
    pattern="On branch ([^[:space:]]*)"
    if [[ ! ${git_status} =~ "(working (tree|directory) clean)" ]]; then
        state="*"
    fi
    if [[ ${git_status} =~ ${pattern} ]]; then
      branch=${match[1]}
      echo "(${branch}${state})"
    fi
}
```

Answer (score 2):

i recommend you to use https://github.com/nojhan/liquidprompt it solves any of this problems and provides you more functionallities and eyecandy for your terminal prompt. I've been using this for the last few months and it's very powerfull.

Comment: Others are also suggesting https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh Oh My Zshell....